# Bundle cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

Im trying to finish the first Android lesson and one of the errors I am getting is "Bundle cannot be resolved to a type"

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

when i view the project properties it has "Android 2.1" by "Android Open Source Project" with platform 2.1 and API level 7. This is checked off as the project build target.

am i using the wrong project build target???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add:

`import android.os.Bundle;`

to your list of imports.

Comment: you are awesome. im also having the same issue with the input fields like textview and whatnot, im assming i just have to import those as well....

Comment: @scarhand: Yes. If you are using Eclipse, `<Ctrl>-<Shift>-<O>` will attempt to automatically add imports for any missing classes and interfaces.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have the "_.Bundle_" already imported but still having the same error in my project !!!?